# Different color for comments with one # and two ## in python

Tags: colorscheme, comments

I would like to know if there is some way to color different comments in python inside VIM.

Today I use wombat256mod and I would like to color in red comments that start with double ## and color with gray the ones that start with a single #

Basically, it would differentiate to me that a ## means an English comment to help understand the code, while the # would just disable a statement in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with the `syntax` and `highlight` commands.

#### Step 1

First, we need to give a regex to match the correct lines, and name each "group"

```
syn match comment /^##.*/ 
syn match disabled /^##\@!.*/
```

The first regex is pretty simple. "Any line starting with two '#' characters". The second regex is slightly more complicated. "Any line starting with a '#', and not followed by another '#'".

#### Step 2

Now we just tell vim what to color text that matches these groups.

```
hi disabled guifg=gray ctermfg=gray
hi comment guifg=red ctermfg=red
```

"guifg" means "the color of the text (foreground) in the gui", and "ctermfg" means "the color of the text (foreground) in the terminal".

Of course, you could choose a different name then "disabled" and "comment". That's up to you.